# Align a middle object vertically in center between 2 other objects

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

[image]

I need to put the red object align in center of middle between black and blue objects...
Which constraints should I add into these objects?

Answer (score 0):

**Ctrl + click** on middle view and **drag to top view** , now leave click and Ctrl. select **Horizontal center**. Make sure you have given height and width constraints to both views as per your requirements[image: This image may help as well].

Now Red and Black , Do same Ctrl + Click + drag from black to red or from red to black, add two constraints. **Leading and Trailing** like in second image[image: This is for Red and Black images]

For adding multiple constraints to single object you may hold **window** key while clicking on attributes.
Hope this helps

Comment: It doesn't work....Theres anyway to do it adding constraint programatically? I think its easier to follow the instructions

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to put red view aligned between blue and black view, you just need to set top and bottom space of red view with a same value.

If you provide enough constraint for them so xcode can calculate each of its frame, your red view would be automatically placed vertically centered between blue and black view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a container view between blue and black views. Place the red view inside the container view and center this red view vertically inside the container view.

**Steps (We'll only consider vertical constraints here):**
1. Add a view (green view in the Screenshot 1).
2. Place the red view inside the green view (i.e, add the red view as a child view to the green view).
3. Add a vertical constraint between green view and blue view (Let the constant of this constraint be 0).
4. Add a vertical constraint between green view and black view (Let the constant of this constraint be 0).
5. Add leading and trailing constraints from red view to green view.
6. Add a "center vertically in Container" constraint from red view to green view.
**Note:**
1. I have set the background color of the container view to be green so that it is easier to explain. You need to change it to clear color so that container view is not visible.
2. You can see the *Screenshot 2* for all the constraints between views.

**Screenshot 1:**
[image: Views]
**Screenshot 2:**
[image: Layout]